# Uploading a Video to Azure Media Services with Python SDKs

Tags: python, azure, azure-media-services

I am currently looking for a way to upload a video to Azure Media Services (AMS v3) via Python SDKs. I have followed its instruction, and am able to connect to AMS successfully.

**Example**

```
credentials = AdalAuthentication(
    context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials,
    RESOURCE,
    CLIENT,
    KEY)

client = AzureMediaServices(credentials, SUBSCRIPTION_ID) # Successful
```

I also successfully get all the videos' details uploaded via its portal

```
for data in client.assets.list(RESOUCE_GROUP_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME).get(0):
    print(f'Asset_name: {data.name}, file_name: {data.description}')

# Asset_name: 4f904060-d15c-4880-8c5a-xxxxxxxx, file_name: 夢想全紀錄.mp4
# Asset_name: 8f2e5e36-d043-4182-9634-xxxxxxxx, file_name: an552Qb_460svvp9.webm
# Asset_name: aef495c1-a3dd-49bb-8e3e-xxxxxxxx, file_name: world_war_2.webm
# Asset_name: b53d8152-6ecd-41a2-a59e-xxxxxxxx, file_name: an552Qb_460svvp9.webm - Media Encoder Standard encoded
```

**However**, when I tried to use the following method; it failed. Since I have no idea what to parse as *parameters* - [Link to Python SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-media/azure.mgmt.media.operations.assetsoperations?view=azure-python)

```
create_or_update(resource_group_name, account_name, asset_name,
                 parameters, custom_headers=None, raw=False, **operation_config)
```

**Therefore**, I would like to ask questions as follows (everything is done via Python SDKs):

1. What kind of parameters does it expect?
2. Can a video be uploaded directly to AMS or it should be uploaded to Blob Storage first?
3. Should an **Asset** contain only one video or multiple files are fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my method to work around using Python SDKs and REST; however, I am not quite sure it's proper.

1. Log-In to Azure Media Services and Blob Storage via Python packages

   ```
   import adal
   from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import AdalAuthentication
   from msrestazure.azure_cloud import AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD
   from azure.mgmt.media import AzureMediaServices
   from azure.mgmt.media.models import MediaService

   from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
   ```
2. Create Assets for an original file and an encoded one by parsing these parameters. Example of the original file Asset creation.

   ```
   asset_name = 'asset-myvideo'
   asset_properties = {
       'properties': {
           'description': 'Original File Description',
           'storageAccountName': "storage-account-name"
       }
   }
   client.assets.create_or_update(RESOUCE_GROUP_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME, asset_name, asset_properties)
   ```
3. Upload a video to the Blob Storage derived from the created original asset

   ```
   current_container = [data.container for data in client.assets.list(RESOUCE_GROUP_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME).get(0) if data.name == asset_name][0] # Get Blob Storage location
   file_name = "myvideo.mp4"
   blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=current_container, blob=file_name)

   with open('original_video.mp4', 'rb') as data:
       blob_client.upload_blob(data)
   print(f'Video uploaded to {current_container}')
   ```

And after that, I do Transform, Job, and Streaming Locator to get the video Streaming Link successfully.

Answer (score 3):

1. The documentation for the REST version of that method is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/assets/createorupdate. This is effectively the same as the Python parameters.
2. Videos are stored in Azure Storage for Media Services.  This is true for input assets, the assets that are encoded, and any streamed content.  It all is in Storage but accessed by Media Services.  You do need to create an asset in Media Services which creates the Storage container.  Once the Storage container exists you upload via the Storage APIs to that Media Services created container.
3. Technically multiple files are fine, but there are a number of issues with doing that that you may not expect.  I'd recommend using 1 input video = 1 Media Services asset.  On the encoding output side there will be more than one file in the asset.  Encoding output contains one or more videos, manifests, and metadata files.

Comment: Currently, I am able to create an asset via REST API based on your answer. I am figuring out how to upload it with such method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with the newer python SDK.   The python documentation is mostly missing, so I constructed this mainly from the python SDK source code and the C# examples.

```
azure-storage-blob==12.3.1
azure-mgmt-media==2.1.0
azure-mgmt-resource==9.0.0
adal~=1.2.2
msrestazure~=0.6.3
```

0) Import a lot of stuff

```python
from azure.mgmt.media.models import Asset, Transform, Job, 
    BuiltInStandardEncoderPreset, TransformOutput, \
    JobInputAsset, JobOutputAsset, AssetContainerSas, AssetContainerPermission

import adal
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import AdalAuthentication
from msrestazure.azure_cloud import AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD
from azure.mgmt.media import AzureMediaServices
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient
import datetime as dt
import time


LOGIN_ENDPOINT = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory
RESOURCE = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory_resource_id

# AzureSettings is a custom NamedTuple
```

1) Log in to AMS:

```python
def get_ams_client(settings: AzureSettings) -> AzureMediaServices:
    context = adal.AuthenticationContext(LOGIN_ENDPOINT + '/' + 
        settings.AZURE_MEDIA_TENANT_ID)
    credentials = AdalAuthentication(
        context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials,
        RESOURCE,
        settings.AZURE_MEDIA_CLIENT_ID,
        settings.AZURE_MEDIA_SECRET
    )
    return AzureMediaServices(credentials, settings.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID)
```

2) Create an input and output asset

```python
input_asset = create_or_update_asset(
    input_asset_name, "My Input Asset", client, azure_settings)
input_asset = create_or_update_asset(
    output_asset_name, "My Output Asset", client, azure_settings)
```

3) Get the Container Name.  (most documentation refers to BlockBlobService, which is seems to have been removed from the SDK)

```python
def get_container_name(client: AzureMediaServices, asset_name: str, settings: AzureSettings):
    expiry_time = dt.datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc) + dt.timedelta(hours=4)
    container_list: AssetContainerSas = client.assets.list_container_sas(
        resource_group_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
        account_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_ACCOUNT_NAME,
        asset_name=asset_name,
        permissions = AssetContainerPermission.read_write,
        expiry_time=expiry_time
    )
    sas_uri: str = container_list.asset_container_sas_urls[0]
    container_client: ContainerClient = ContainerClient.from_container_url(sas_uri)
    return container_client.container_name
```

4) Upload a file the the input asset container:

```python
def upload_file_to_asset_container(
    container: str, local_file, uploaded_file_name, settings: AzureSettings):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(settings.AZURE_MEDIA_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING))
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container, blob=uploaded_file_name)

    with open(local_file, 'rb') as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

5) Create a transform (in my case, using the adaptive streaming preset):

```python
def get_or_create_transform(
    client: AzureMediaServices,
    transform_name: str,
    settings: AzureSettings):
    transform_output = TransformOutput(preset=BuiltInStandardEncoderPreset(preset_name="AdaptiveStreaming"))
    transform: Transform = client.transforms.create_or_update(
        resource_group_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
        account_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_ACCOUNT_NAME,
        transform_name=transform_name,
        outputs=[transform_output]
    )
    return transform
```

5) Submit the Job

```python
def submit_job(
    client: AzureMediaServices,
    settings: AzureSettings,
    input_asset: Asset,
    output_asset: Asset,
    transform_name: str,
    correlation_data: dict) -> Job:

    job_input = JobInputAsset(asset_name=input_asset.name)
    job_outputs = [JobOutputAsset(asset_name=output_asset.name)]
    job: Job = client.jobs.create(
        resource_group_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
        account_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_ACCOUNT_NAME,
        job_name=f"test_job_{UNIQUENESS}",
        transform_name=transform_name,
        parameters=Job(input=job_input,
            outputs=job_outputs,
            correlation_data=correlation_data)
    )
    return job
```

6) Then I get the URLs after the Event Grid has told me the job is done:

```python
# side-effect warning: this starts the streaming endpoint $$$
def get_urls(client: AzureMediaServices, output_asset_name: str
    locator_name: str):

    try:
        locator: StreamingLocator = client.streaming_locators.create(
            resource_group_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
            account_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_ACCOUNT_NAME,
            streaming_locator_name=locator_name,
            parameters=StreamingLocator(
                asset_name=output_asset_name,
                streaming_policy_name="Predefined_ClearStreamingOnly"
            )
        )
    except Exception as ex:
        print("ignoring existing")

    streaming_endpoint: StreamingEndpoint = client.streaming_endpoints.get(
        resource_group_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
        account_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_ACCOUNT_NAME,
        streaming_endpoint_name="default")

    if streaming_endpoint:
        if streaming_endpoint.resource_state != "Running":
            client.streaming_endpoints.start(
                resource_group_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
                account_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                streaming_endpoint_name="default"
            )

    paths = client.streaming_locators.list_paths(
        resource_group_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME,
        account_name=settings.AZURE_MEDIA_ACCOUNT_NAME,
        streaming_locator_name=locator_name
    )
    return [f"https://{streaming_endpoint.host_name}{path.paths[0]}" for path in paths.streaming_paths]
```